# Erro em testes com python 3.7, pytest e flask Blueprint

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Estou iniciando um aplicação Flask bem básico para fins de aprendizagem. O apps esta rodando normalmente. o Problema são os teste com pytest.

Estou usando no pipenv: python 3.7.2, Flask==1.0.2, pytest-flask==0.14.0 e pytest==4.3.0

estrutura do projeto.

`├── setup.py
├── manager.py
├── tests
│   ├── test_root.py
│   ├── conftest.py
│   └── pytest.ini
└── app
    ├── __init__.py
    └── main.py`

---

manager.py

```
import click
from app import app

@click.group()
def order():
    """To use command line."""
    ...

@order.command()
def runserver():
    """To run a server: runserver."""
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

`app/main.py`

```
from flask import Blueprint

main_bp = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@main_bp.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def root():
    """Root page."""
    return "<h1> Home Page </h1>"
```

---

`app/__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from .main import main_bp    

def create_app():
    """Create app and config blueprint."""
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.register_blueprint(main_bp, url_prefix='/')

    return app    

app = create_app()
```

---

`app/test/pytest.ini`

```
[vazio]
```

---

`app/test/conftest.py`

```
import pytest
from app import create_app

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    """Client fixture config."""
    return create_app().test_client()
```

---

`app/test/test_root.py`

```
import pytest
from flask import Flask, url_for
from app import app

def test_root_should_return_200(client):
    """Test root page."""
    assert client.get('/').status_code == 200

def test_about_should_return_200(client):
    """Test about page."""
    assert client.get(url_for('main.about', external=True)).status_code == 200
```

Quando uso `assert client.get('/').status_code == 200` o teste passa normal mente.

Quando uso o `url_for` o teste não passa `assert client.get(url_for('main.about', external=True)).status_code`

e tenho o seguinte erro:

---

```
tests/test_root.py::test_root_should_return_200 PASSED                                                                      [ 50%]
tests/test_root.py::test_about_should_return_200 FAILED                                                                     [100%]

========================================= FAILURES =================================
_____________________________ test_about_should_return_200 ____________
endpoint = 'main.about', values = {'external': True}, appctx = None, reqctx = None

    def url_for(endpoint, **values):
        """Generates a URL to the given endpoint with the method provided.

        Variable arguments that are unknown to the target endpoint are appended
        to the generated URL as query arguments.  If the value of a query argument
        is ``None``, the whole pair is skipped.  In case blueprints are active
        you can shortcut references to the same blueprint by prefixing the
        local endpoint with a dot (``.``).
```

...

```
E           RuntimeError: Attempted to generate a URL without the application context being pushed. This has to be executed when application context is available.

/home/mn/.local/share/virtualenvs/CTRLEstoque-ukt8lCc8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py:294: RuntimeError
=============================================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.34 seconds =======================================
```

Aguem poderia me ajudar com esse erro???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro diz que você não está no contexto da aplicação ao tentar gerar a URL com a função `url_for`. No arquivo de criação da fixture em `conftest.py` você pode em vez de retornar o client, retornar a aplicação. Então ficaria desse jeito:

```py
import pytest
from app import create_app

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    """Client fixture config."""
    return create_app()
```

Uma vez feito isso, seu teste então passará a ser da seguinte maneira:

```py
import pytest
from flask import Flask, url_for
from app import app

def test_root_should_return_200(app):
    """Test root page."""
    assert app.test_client().get('/').status_code == 200

def test_about_should_return_200(app):
    """Test about page."""
    app.app_context().push()
    assert app.test_client().get(url_for('main.about', external=True)).status_code == 200
```

`app.app_context().push()` efetua o push do contexto da aplicação. Desta forma, você estará dentro do contexto da aplicação quando efetuar o `assert`.

Comment: Obrigado Igor, entendi claramente agora, ainda tenho muito que estudar para melhorar... Obrigado.